# how to add elements to an array when looping

Tags: reactjs

I want to start a loop and add a certain number of elements to the array. "newTester + =" does not add values ​​to the array. How to solve the problem?

```
state = {
tester: []
}

handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({tableAmountColumns: value});
        let i;
        let newTester;
        for ( i = 0; i < value; i++) {
           newTester +=
               {
                   key: 1,
                   qwe: "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
               };
            this.setState({ tester: [...this.state.tester, newTester ] })
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newTester` needs to be initialized as an empty array, otherwise its value is `undefined`. You can't `+=` anything to `undefined` (or to an array, for that matter). You need to `push()` elements into it:

```js
handleChange(value) {
  this.setState({tableAmountColumns: value});
  let newTester = [];  // <-- Important!
  for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    newTester.push({ key: 1, qwe: "<h1>Hello world!</h1>" });
  }
  this.setState({ tester: [...this.state.tester, ...newTester] })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an empty array as a default value for `newTester` variable and then push objects. Also, you can take `setState` call for setting `tester` state outside of the for loop and merge two `setState` calls for setting `tester` and `tableAmountColumns` values in order to avoid multiple rerenders.

EDIT: Also, spread `newTester` array while setting `tester` state.

```
state = {
tester: []
}

handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({});
        let i;
        let newTester = [];
        for ( i = 0; i < value; i++) {
           newTester.push(
               {
                   key: 1,
                   qwe: "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
               });
        }
        this.setState({
          tableAmountColumns: value,
          tester: [...this.state.tester, ...newTester ]
        })
    }
```